# How to use Polly with Flurl.Http?

Tags: c#, httpresponse, polly, flurl

Currently I have this request:

```
await url
    .SetQueryParams(queryString)
    .SetClaimsToken()
    .GetJsonAsync<T>()
```

I'd like to start using Polly (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) now to handle retries and provide a better user experience. For instance, not "hanging up" on the user on the first attempt due to bad network connection. This is the example I was trying to use:

```
int[] httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = { 408, 500, 502, 503, 504 };
Policy
    .Handle<HttpException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponse>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains(r.StatusCode))
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                })
    .ExecuteAsync( await url... )
```

But it requires `HttpResponse` to be the return type. As you can see from my Flurl example, it's returning `T`, even though it is an `HttpResponse`. The `T` is just the type used to deserialize the `StringContent`.

This first example is not working at all since I'm using it inside a PCL and I can't get a reference to `System.Web` there. So I tried this:

```
Policy
    .HandleResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    .OrResult(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
    .OrResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
    })
    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        await url...
    });
```

But this one also doesn't work because Polly expects `HttpStatusCode` as return type. So my question is: How can I tell polly to handle those `HttpStatusCode`s and still allow my return of type `T`?

Comment: You can also [register a global Polly policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284010/62600) that Flurl will use by default with every call it makes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770071/what-are-the-http-codes-to-automatically-retry-the-request Has slightly different list of HTTP codes valid for retry - 408 ,425, 429, 500,502-504

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Polly can interpret any value returned by a delegate executed through a policy, as a fault.  However, as you observed, the call to `.GetJsonAsync<T>()` in your posted example:

```
await url
    .SetQueryParams(queryString)
    .SetClaimsToken()
    .GetJsonAsync<T>()
```

is returning `T`.  The call hides `HttpResponseMessage` by going straight to Json deserialization to `T`.

You'd need to use an overload in flurl which returns something around `HttpResponseMessage`. I haven't used flurl, but [this overload](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/HttpExtensions.cs#L247) returning `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` looks promising.  You could probably do something like:

```
List<int> httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = new List<int>(new[] {408, 500, 502, 503, 504});
HttpResponseMessage response = await Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>() 
    .Or<OtherExceptions>() // add other exceptions if you find your call may throw them, eg FlurlHttpException
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains((int)r.StatusCode))
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[] {
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
                })
    .ExecuteAsync(() => 
       url
        .SetQueryParams(queryString)
        .SetClaimsToken()
        .GetAsync()
    );

T responseAsT = await Task.FromResult(response).ReceiveJson<T>();
```

The call to `.ReceiveJson<T>()` at the end is suggested simply be comparing the flurl source code for your original call `.GetJsonAsync<T>()` [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/HttpExtensions.cs#L181) with the substituted `.GetAsync();` [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/HttpExtensions.cs#L170).

Of course you could wrap it all into a concise extension helper method on flurl, perhaps something like this:

```
async T GetJsonAsyncResiliently<T>(this IFlurlClient client, Policy policy) // OR (if preferred): this Url url instead of IFlurlClient client
{
    return await Task.FromResult(policy.ExecuteAsync(() => client.GetAsync())).ReceiveJson<T>();
}
```

**EDIT**: I may have pointed to the wrong flurl overloads for your case, in pointing to methods on `IFlurlClient`.  However, a parallel set of extension methods exist within flurl on `Url` and `string`, so the same principles apply.

Comment: @eestein Made some minor syntax adjustments after downloading flurl.  Does this get you sorted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, gonna test it now!

Comment: Thank you, I was able to adapt my code using your examples! :)

Answer (score 20):

You shouldn't need to break from using convenience methods like `GetJsonAsync<T>()`, because Flurl throws an exception on non-2XX responses (or however you [configure](https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/) it), which should allow it to play very nicely with Polly. Just remove the `.Handle<HttpException>` and `.OrResult<HttpResponse>` parts in your original code and handle `FlurlHttpException` instead:

```
T poco = await Policy
    .Handle<FlurlHttpException>(ex => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Contains((int)ex.Call.Response.StatusCode))
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(...)
    .ExecuteAsync(() => url
        .SetQueryParams(queryString)
        .SetClaimsToken()
        .GetJsonAsync<T>());
```

And just a suggestion for cleaning that up further:

```
T poco = await Policy
    .Handle<FlurlHttpException>(IsWorthRetrying)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(...)
    .ExecuteAsync(() => url
        .SetQueryParams(queryString)
        .SetClaimsToken()
        .GetJsonAsync<T>());

private bool IsWorthRetrying(FlurlHttpException ex) {
    switch ((int)ex.Call.Response.StatusCode) {
        case 408:
        case 500:
        case 502:
        case 504:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks nice, Todd! I had wondered about this kind of approach too.  I hadn't initially recommended as I wasn't sure that all flurl calls guarantee to return a `FlurlHttpException`.  For instance, https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/FlurlClient.cs#L201 (which is public) doesn't trap?  But agree this pattern is really nice with the `.GetJsonAsync<T>())`.  Nice library, btw.

Comment: @mountaintraveller If a call completes and the response contains a non-success status, a `FlurlHttpException` is _virtually_ guaranteed. At least that is the intended, documented behavior. But if it's a concern, it certainly can't hurt to keep the other Polly configs in there. (Thanks, and your lib looks pretty sweet too! It's giving me ideas for adding retries to Flurl :))

Comment: @mountaintraveller btw, the line you highlighted doesn't trap the error because it gets trapped/rethrown as a `FlurlHttpExcepton` deeper down in [FlurlMessageHandler](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/Configuration/FlurlMessageHandler.cs)

Comment: @ToddMenier Nice!  I hadn't spotted the custom `HttpMessageHandler` registered on `HttpClient` by the default factory.  This https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http.Shared/Configuration/FlurlMessageHandler.cs#L25 was a really nice read!

Comment: @ToddMenier , is this code suppose to compile? I'm getting a cannot convert Task T to Task <HttpResponseMessage> for the ExecuteAsync

Comment: @Robin yes it should compile. My example isn't using `HttpResponseMessage` at all, are you sure you're following it correctly?

Comment: @ToddMenier, thanks, I found the issue, I added a OrResult before Wait, and it changes that to HTTPResponseMessage as a return type.

Btw, IsWorthReTrying needs to do null check for .Call,I'm getting null exception if url is not valid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770071/what-are-the-http-codes-to-automatically-retry-the-request/74627395#74627395 has couple more statuses to add to IsWorthRetrying

Answer (score 5):

Configure Flurl by setting the `HttpClientFactory` that can be configured with Polly and create a custom `HttpClientFactory`:

```
public class MyCustomHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory, IMyCustomHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public MyCustomHttpClientFactory(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    public override HttpClient CreateHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        return _httpClient;
    }
}
```

Register that Service in `ConfigureServices` with:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddHttpClient<IMyCustomHttpClientFactory, MyCustomHttpClientFactory>()
        .SetHandlerLifetime(...)
        .AddPolicyHandler(....);
}
```

And assign that Factory to Flurl:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Get HttpClientFactory and Configure Flurl to use it.
    var factory = (IMyCustomHttpClientFactory)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IMyCustomHttpClientFactory));
    FlurlHttp.Configure((settings) => settings.HttpClientFactory = factory);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated answer to use [Polly v8.2](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/releases/tag/8.2.0) with [Flurl v4](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/releases/tag/Flurl.Http.4.0.0) and Dependency Injection. Polly v8 was released November 2023 and Flurl v4 was released December 2023.

The new Flurl AddMiddleware() method is not currently compatible with Polly v8.

I am posting this because I currently prefer how Flurl builds urls and how Flurl.Http executes http requests over the stock HttpClient.

Polly transitioned from Policies in v7 to Strategies & Pipelines in v8. .NET 8 was released in December 2023 and around the same time Microsoft released the Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience package to integrate Polly v8 with HttpClient. This blog post by Microsoft covers [Building resilient cloud services with .NET 8.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-resilient-cloud-services-with-dotnet-8/)

This is a workaround until Flurl.Http's FlurlClientCache directly supports Polly v8 (or until Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience produces a binding that works with FlurlClientCache.AddMiddleware()). This requires installing:

- [Flurl 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl)
- [Flurl.Http 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http)
- [Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience 8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Resilience)

In Program.cs, setup a HttpClient with the Polly v8 resilience handler using Dependency Injection:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("testendpoint", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
    })
    .AddStandardResilienceHandler(options =>
    {
        // Customize retry
        options.Retry.ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>()
            .Handle<TimeoutRejectedException>()
            .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
            .HandleResult(response => response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false);
        options.Retry.MaxRetryAttempts = 5;
    });
```

In your method, use Dependency Injection to inject an HttpClientFactory and use it to create an HttpClient to use with FlurlClient:

```
public class Example
{
    
    private readonly ILogger _logger;         
    private readonly FlurlClient _exampleClient;
        
    public Example(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,         
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {

            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Example>();            
            
            _exampleClient = new FlurlClient(httpClientFactory.CreateClient("testendpoint"));
            _exampleClient.Settings.JsonSerializer = new DefaultJsonSerializer(DefaultOptions);
             
        }
        
    private async Task<Payload> Test()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Testing!";

        try
        {

            var request = await _exampleClient
                    .Request()                                              
                    .ReceiveJson<Payload>();
            

            return request;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Exception!");
            throw;
        }
    }
    
    public class Payload {
        public string ExamplePayload {get; set;}
    }
    
    public static JsonSerializerOptions DefaultOptions = new()
        {
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
            WriteIndented = true,
            DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault,
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            IncludeFields = true
        }
    
}
```

The above example also shows how to setup the Flurl serializer to use the JsonSerializerOptions of System.Text.Json.

Comment: It's interesting that you declare Flurl 4 and Polly 8 to be incompatible, then demonstrate exactly how you might do it. I haven't looked much at the new resiliency stuff yet, if it's no longer middleware-driven (which would be a surprise), then perhaps the best way to do it is like you described. But Flurl is dependency-free so always a matter of adapting it to other libraries one way or another. To say they're impatible I think is just wrong.

Comment: Good point, I edited and clarified the post. I was intending to focus on the new FlurlClientCache for Dependency Injection and the AddMiddleware configuration - these work great with Polly v7.