# Set a default Polly policy with Flurl

Tags: c#, polly, flurl

I'm currently using Polly and Flurl together, but I have a common retry policy that I have to add to every request. I notice that Polly allows you to set a default using `AddPolicyHandler(...)` but this requires an `IHttpClientBuilder` and I can't see any way of getting hold of this from Flurl.

I thought overloading `DefaultHttpClientFactory` might be the way to go, but that only gives me access to the `HttpClient`, not the `IHttpClientBuilder`.

I know I could make my own `HttpClient`s and pass them into Flurl, but I'd rather avoid that if I can as I'd like Flurl to manage their lifecycle.

Is there currently a way of doing what I want to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question. Flurl gives you all the necessary hooks to do this. First define a `DelegatingHandler` that takes a Polly policy:

```
public class PollyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _policy;

    public PollyHandler(IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy) {
        _policy = policy;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return _policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => base.SendAsync(request, ct), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then create a custom `IHttpClientFactory` that returns your custom handler with the default handler as its `InnerHandler`:

```
public class PollyFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _policy;

    public PollyFactory(IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy) {
        _policy = policy;
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
        return new PollyHandler(_policy) {
            InnerHandler = base.CreateMessageHandler()
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, on app startup, define your policy and register it with Flurl:

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .RetryAsync(5);

FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.HttpClientFactory = new PollyFactory(policy));
```

One important note is that **this approach will not work with a policy that handles FlurlHttpException**. That's because you're intercepting calls at the `HttpMessageHandler` level here. Flurl converts responses and errors to `FlurlHttpException`s higher up the stack, so those won't get trapped/retried with this approach. The policy in the example above traps `HttpRequestException` and `HttpResponseMessage` (with non-2XX status codes), which will work.

Comment: When is FlurlHttpException thrown vs HttpRequestException?

Comment: @Robin HttpRequestException is thrown inside any message handler you have configured, like above. `FlurlHttpException` is thrown by Flurl upon completion of any HTTP call, after those handlers have run. If you're doing try/catch within the normal flow of your app logic, `FlurlHttpException` is what you want to catch.

Comment: How do I use it without the factory? This only calls it once 


`string s = await Policy
                .Handle<HttpRequestException> () 
                .OrResult <HttpResponseMessage> (r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                .RetryAsync (5)
                .ExecuteAsync (() => { Console.WriteLine ("Retry"); return "http://127.0.0:7071/".GetAsync (); })
                .ReceiveString ()
               .ConfigureAwait (false);`

Comment: @Robin Please ask a new question.

Comment: Good idea, the formatting doesn't work in comments , took over many edits and unable to format properly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718410/how-to-use-flurl-with-polly-without-factory

Comment: @ToddMenier According to Stephen Cleary it is not a good idea to use Polly inside the HttpClient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769241/polly-waitandretryasync-hangs-after-one-retry

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same functionality on Flurl.http v4, you would register the delegation handler as middleware, which is nicely simplified from the old way of achieving this.

As before you start with a `DelegationHandler` that takes a polly policy:

```cs
public class PollyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _policy;

    public PollyHandler(IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy) {
        _policy = policy;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return _policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => base.SendAsync(request, ct), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And then you define your policy and register this as middleware on startup:

```cs
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .RetryAsync(5);

FlurlHttp.Clients.WithDefaults(clientBuilder => clientBuilder.AddMiddleware(() => new PollyHandler(policy)));
```

Comment: Why do you need to define a custom `PollyHandler`? Can't you just use the [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/83947bf3bc084c8f6655c5cbd07d2f7bc2fbd928/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs)?

Comment: FYI...This will only work with Polly v7. I gave a workaround for Polly v8 in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745809/how-to-use-polly-with-flurl-http/77672447#77672447

Comment: I have just verified on my side this does work on flurl v4 and polly v8.2.0.

registering the policy as described above you can then run it using the string extention methods for instance and it will execute as expected.
```csharp
var result = await "http://localhost:3000/api/something".GetJsonAsync<dynamic>();
```

however I am not sure if this would be considered industry best practice, but it is as far as I have experimented the simplest way to upgrade your old project if done on the way described above.