# How to use Flurl with Polly without factory

Tags: polly, flurl

Following from [Set a default Polly policy with Flurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272374/set-a-default-polly-policy-with-flurl)

How do I use Polly with Flurl without the factory? This only calls it once

```
string s = await Policy
                        .Handle<HttpRequestException> ()
                        .OrResult <HttpResponseMessage> (r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        .RetryAsync (5)
                        .ExecuteAsync (() => { Console.WriteLine ("Retry"); return "http://127.0.0:7071/".GetAsync (); })
                        .ReceiveString ()
                        .ConfigureAwait (false);
```

Comment: Have you tried `Handle<FlurlHttpException>` instead? That is what you want to catch in this scenario instead of `HttpRequestException`. I might not have explained that very well in the comments in the question you linked to.

Comment: ok, got it working. thanks

Comment: @Robin why don't you answer your own question so that other people can learn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Polly with Flurl.Http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745809/how-to-use-polly-with-flurl-http)