# Polly WaitAndRetryAsync hangs after one retry

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retry-logic, exponential-backoff

I'm using Polly in very basic scenario to do exponential backoff if an HTTP call fails:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<TimeoutException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(4, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(3, retryAttempt)))
        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false));
}

private static PolicyBuilder<HttpResponseMessage> HandleTransientHttpError()
{
    return Policy
        .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => (int)response.StatusCode >= 500 || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
        .Or<HttpRequestException>();
}
```

I have a test API that just creates an `HttpListener` and loops in a `while(true)`. Currently, I'm trying to test if the client retries correctly when receiving 500 for every single call.

```
while (true)
{
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    //Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
}
```

With the above code all works well and the retries happen after 3, 9, 27 and 81 seconds of waiting, respectively.

However, if I uncomment the `Thread.Sleep` call, the client retries once and then just hangs until the call times out for the other 3 retries, which is not the correct behavior.

The same thing also happens with the actual production API, which leads me to believe it's not a problem with my test API.

Comment: Try to `ConfigureAwait(false)` the awaiting of `HandleTransientHttpError()`.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias: Unfortunately, that did not solve it. The context in which I'm executing this is similar to a console application, so I don't think it would make a difference theoretically either.

Comment: Is this on .NET Framework? 4.6.1? It looks like an example of this issue: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/642  . That issue is outside (not caused by) Polly - see discussion on .https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/642 and https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/658

Comment: @mountain traveller: It is on .NET Framework 4.6.1 indeed.

Comment: @Tundor : Did you got any fix for it?

Comment: @AstroBoy: Yes, I moved the Polly retry logic outside the actual http call, as Stephen Cleary suggests below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Polly *within* `HttpClient` doesn't work very well. A single `SendAsync` is intended to be a single call. I.e.:

- Any `HttpClient` timeouts will apply to the single `SendAsync` call.
- Some versions of `HttpClient` also dispose their content, so it can't
  be reused in the next `SendAsync` call.
- As noted in the comments,
  this kind of hang is a [known
  issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/642) and cannot be
  fixed by Polly.

Bottom line: overriding `SendAsync` is great for adding pre-request and post-request logic. It's not the right place to retry.

Instead, use a regular `HttpClient` and have your Polly logic retry *outside* the `GetStringAsync` (or whatever) call.

Comment: Any thoughts on the workaround by disposing the results inside the RetryAsync callback?

Comment: @scuba88: I haven't tried it. As long as it doesn't close the underlying socket, it might work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an appropriate workaround for the known issue with .NET Framework and using Polly within the HttpClient.  We must dispose the result on retry in order to allow multiple requests. See discussion on the original issue [here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/642) and another discussion describing the workaround [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/1700).  I have only briefly tested this to determine that it works, but have not fully researched what side-effects might be present.

```
Policy
.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
.OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(msg => RetryableStatusCodesPredicate(msg.StatusCode))
.RetryAsync(retryCount, onRetry: (x, i) =>
{
    x.Result.Dispose(); // workaround for https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1700
}));
```