# Flurl: Retry http call automatically after handling 401 response

Tags: c#, .net, rest-client, session-management, flurl

Using Flurl, I am trying to implement an elegant solution to handle 401 responses for several APIs.

I can trap HTTP exceptions using:

`FlurlHttp.GlobalSettings.OnError = MyFlurlErrorHandler;`

And then:

```
private void MyFlurlErrorHandler(HttpCall httpCall)
{
    if (httpCall.HttpStatus == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)       //401
    {
         //some code here will refresh our access token to take care of the 401 error

         //SESSION MANAGEMENT HERE
         httpCall.ExceptionHandled = true
    }
}
```

Once the error is handled, how do I automatically retry the original httpCall here before setting ExceptionHandled = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurl has nothing built-in to do retries, although it is on the roadmap. Until then I recommend [using Polly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745809/how-to-use-polly-with-flurl-http).