# Cannot Configure Flurl to use Polly PolicyHandler

Tags: c#, polly, flurl

I have a .NET HostedService which uses dependency injection. My client factory creates a policy handler and in DI I configure Flurl to use the factory. In debug mode I can see that clients are generated by the factory which use the `TransientFaultPolicyHandler` but I don't get any retries.

**Program.cs**

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IFlurlClientFactory, PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory>();

FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
{
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new PollyHttpClientFactory();    
});
```

**PollyHttpClientFactory**

```cs
public class PollyHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return new TransientFaultPolicyHandler
        {
             InnerHandler = base.CreateMessageHandler()
        };
    }

    public override HttpClient CreateHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        return new HttpClient(CreateMessageHandler());
    }
}
```

**TransientFaultPolicyHandler.cs**

```cs
public class TransientFaultPolicyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Policy.Handle<FlurlHttpException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, attempt =>
            {
                var nextAttempt = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt));
                //$"Retry attempt {attempt} to make request. Next try on {nextAttempt.TotalSeconds} seconds.";
                return nextAttempt;
            })
            .ExecuteAsync(token => base.SendAsync(request, token), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flurl but why did you define the retry policy inside the `DelegatingHandler`?

Comment: Mainly because I could and I was in a hurry to implement something. Never good coding in a rush I admit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Polly with Flurl.Http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745809/how-to-use-polly-with-flurl-http)

Answer (score 1):

This does actually work. I was using an IDE that I'm not very familiar with and so couldn't see it being called.